Zeta function related double integral
I recently came across the following double Integral:
$$
I(a)=\int \limits_{0}^{1}\int \limits_{0}^{1}\frac{x^ay^a}{1-xy}dx\,dy
$$
which can be easily shown to be equal to:
$$
I(a)=\zeta(2,a)=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}
$$
where:
$$
\zeta(s,a)=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+a)^s}
$$
given that, if we differentiate both sides with respect to $a$, $m$-times, we get:
$$
\frac{\partial^m}{\partial a^m}\int \limits_{0}^{1}\int \limits_{0}^{1}\frac{x^ay^a}{1-xy}dx\,dy=\frac{\partial^m}{\partial a^m}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}
\\
\int \limits_{0}^{1}\int \limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(xy)^mx^ay^a}{1-xy}dx\,dy=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m(m+1)!}{(n+a)^{m+2}}
\\
\frac{(-1)^m}{(m+1)!}\int \limits_{0}^{1}\int \limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(xy)^mx^ay^a}{1-xy}dx\,dy=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+a)^{m+2}}
$$
Now making a change of variable $(m+2=s)$, we get:
$$
\frac{(-1)^s}{(s-1)!}\int \limits_{0}^{1}\int \limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(xy)^{s-2}x^ay^a}{1-xy}dx\,dy=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+a)^{s}}=\zeta(s,a)
$$
which can also be expressed as:
$$
\zeta(s,a)\Gamma(s)=(-1)^s\int \limits_{0}^{1}\int \limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(xy)^{s-2}x^ay^a}{1-xy}dx\,dy
$$
And so to finally get to my question, how would one go about evaluating the following double integral without using sums, which would lead right back to the definition of the zeta function?

You could have shown $I(a)=\zeta(2,a)$ faster using $\frac1{1-xy}=\sum_{n\ge 0} (xy)^n$

Well i did use it in order to evaluate $I(a)$. Or do you mean that it would be more clear this way?

Substitute $ \displaystyle \left\{\, xy=u,\,y=v \Rightarrow dx=\frac{1}{v}\,du,\,dy=dv \,\right\} $ with 
Integration Limits $ \displaystyle \left\{\, \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\,dx\,dy \mapsto\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{v}\,du\,dv \,\right\} $ then 
Change Integration Order $ \displaystyle \left\{\, \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{v}\,du\,dv \mapsto\int_{0}^{1}\int_{u}^{1}\,dv\,du \,\right\} $
$$ 
\begin{align} \color{red}{I(a)} 
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x\,y)^{a}}{1-x\,y}\,dx\,dy \\[3mm] 
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\color{blue}{0}}^{\color{blue}{v}}\frac{u^{a}}{1-u}\,\frac{1}{v}\,\color{blue}{du\,dv} =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\color{blue}{u}}^{\color{blue}{1}}\frac{u^{a}}{1-u}\,\frac{1}{v}\,\color{blue}{dv\,du} \\[3mm] 
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{a}}{1-u} \left( \int_{u}^{1}\,\frac{1}{v}\,dv\right) du =-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{a}\log(u)}{1-u}\,du \\[3mm] 
&\qquad\qquad \color{blue}{\small{\left\{ u=e^{-t} \Rightarrow du=-e^{-t}\,dt,\quad \int_{0}^{1}du \mapsto\int_{\infty}^{0}dt \right\}}} \\[1mm] 
&=-\int_{\infty}^{0}\frac{e^{-at}\,(-t)}{1-e^{-t}}\left(-e^{-t}\right)dt =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t\,e^{-(1+a)t}}{1-e^{-t}}\,dt \\[3mm] 
&=\Gamma(2)\,\zeta(2,1+a)=\color{red}{\zeta(2,1+a)} \\[3mm] 
&=\sum_{n=\color{red}{0}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1+a)^2} =\sum_{n=\color{red}{1}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+a)^2} 
\end{align} 
$$

$$ 
\begin{align} \color{red}{I(s,a)} 
&=(-1)^{s}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x\,y)^{a}\log^{s-2}(xy)}{1-(x\,y)}\,dx\,dy \\[3mm] 
&=(-1)^{s}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\color{blue}{0}}^{\color{blue}{v}}\frac{u^{a}\log^{s-2}(u)}{1-u}\,\frac{1}{v}\,\color{blue}{du\,dv} =(-1)^{s}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\color{blue}{u}}^{\color{blue}{1}}\frac{u^{a}\log^{s-2}(u)}{1-u}\,\frac{1}{v}\,\color{blue}{dv\,du} \\[3mm] 
&=(-1)^{s}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{a}\log^{s-2}(u)}{1-u} \left( \int_{u}^{1}\,\frac{1}{v}\,dv\right) du =(-1)^{s-1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{a}\log^{s-1}(u)}{1-u}\,du \\[3mm] 
&=(-1)^{s-1}\int_{\infty}^{0}\frac{e^{-at}\,(-t)^{s-1}}{1-e^{-t}}\left(-e^{-t}\right)dt =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}\,e^{-(1+a)t}}{1-e^{-t}}\,dt \\[3mm] 
&=\color{red}{\Gamma(s)\,\zeta(s,1+a)} 
\end{align} 
$$
$\zeta(s,a)$ Hurwitz Zeta function
